# how to switch blocking mode of socketchannel?

Tags: java, nio, socketchannel

I use `SocketChannel` to receive TCP stream from server on client side. For example:

```
Selector selector=Selector.open();
SocketChannel mychannel=SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress(ip,port));
channel.configureBlocking(false);
SelectionKey channelkey=channel.register(selector,SelectionKey.OP_READ);
```

Then, I can use the `selector.select()` method to handle reading problem.

```
while(true){
    if(selector.select()!=0){
       Iterator<SelectionKey> it=selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
       while(it.hasNext()){
         SelectionKey key=it.next();
         it.remove();
         if(key.isReadable()){
            if(key.equals(channelkey)){

               //concrete handle
               ...
            }
         }
       }
    }
}
```

With concrete handle,considering I'd like to use InputStream(I wanna read stream line) to receive tcp stream from server side,there are two methods.One is using `channel.socket()`, another is to use Channels. Here I use `channel.socket()`, for example:

```
SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
key.cancel();
channel.configureBlocking(true);
InputStream ins = Channels.newInputStream(channel);
InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(ins,"utf-8");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(is);
String res = in.readLine();
while (!res.equals("")) {
    System.out.println(res);
    res = in.readLine();
}
       ......①
```

OK, now I finish reading tcp stream for one time.In order to continue to using selector, I should set channel blocking mode to false.

```
    channel.configureBlocking(false);
```

The question is,the key that combines channel and selector has been canceled.I want to register mychannel again.What should I do? It seems that if I use `mychannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ)` again on ①, it throws `Exception`.

My run() method code is as follows:

```
try {
if (selector.select(getTimeout()) != 0) {
    Iterator<SelectionKey> it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        SelectionKey key = it.next();
        if (key.isReadable()) {
            SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
            key.cancel();
            channel.configureBlocking(true);
            InputStream ins = Channels.newInputStream(channel);
            InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(ins,"utf-8");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(is);
            String res = in.readLine();
            while (!res.equals("")) {
                System.out.println("========" + res);
                res = in.readLine();
            }
            channel.configureBlocking(false);
            System.out.println(key.isValid());
            proxykey=channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
        }
        it.remove();
    }
}
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The Exception it throws is:

```
    Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException
at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.ensureValid(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.interestOps(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractSelectableChannel.register(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.channels.SelectableChannel.register(Unknown Source)
at AgentThread.run(AgentThread.java:185)
```

Comment: Throws *what* exception?

Comment: thanks.I'd like to edit the question to show my run method code and what exception it throws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectionKey.cancel()` doesn't take full effect until the next `select()`, for various arcane reasons. You could try calling `selectNow()` after the cancel, or maybe better just before the re-registration.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you.But I'm complexed with socketchannel reading tcp stream.How can I read the absolute bytes number as I want?For example,my bytebuffer allocates 512 bytes,it reads 512 bytes at a time(assume the tcp stream is continuous),I just want to get 200 bytes of it(and the rest is important for next reading),what can I do?Thank you very much.

Comment: @William Allocate a 200-byte ByteBuffer, or else call `limit(200).`

Comment: @EJPThe question is the part's size I need is uncertain,but it's distinguished with a blank line.

Comment: @William I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @EJPI mean I take 200 bytes just for example.I don't konw exactly the size of the part I want ,the only condition is that it is distinguished from next stream info from a blank line.I hope I have explain it clear.

Comment: @William No, you haven't explained it at all. You already have code to read to a blank line, which gets you past the HTTP headers. What do you need now?

Comment: @EJPOh,I konw your confusion.The question of "How can I read the absolute bytes number as I want" is an independent question which I hope you teach me some better idea instead of the one I used.

Comment: @William So is it that you want to *replace* that header reading code? You're not making yourself at all clear.

Comment: @EJPyes,sorry to make trouble.I'm new here and in English.